# Socket programming in c connection failed

Tags: c, sockets

Trying to practice socket programming in c. Been hitting an error of `Connection Failed`but not sure why. I included both the server and client code. I believe the problem is with `connect`.
Also, i run the client first then run the server. Is that the right way to compile it?

//CLIENT

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PORT 8080

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int sock = 0, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char *hello = "Hello from client";
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }
    send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
    printf("Hello message sent\n");
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n",buffer );
    return 0;
}
```

//SERVER

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PORT 8080
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
                                                  &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                                 sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n",buffer );
    send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
    printf("Hello message sent\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, your `setsockopt` call on the server is wrong. The option to set is not a bitmask; [you can only set **one** option at a time](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsockopt.html). Fixing that and the slurry of missing headers from the client, and this "works" (term used loosely). And you should run the server first. He's the one waiting for connections.

Comment: how would i fix the `setsockopt` call?

Comment: @NeverSleepAlwaysCode Call `setsockopt()` multiple times, each with a different option.

Comment: No, you should run the server first. If the server is not running, there is nobody listening to incoming connections, and yes, the connection attempt gets refused.